Sign in failed: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem
I am using php drupal framework and php version is 7.4

Kreait\Firebase\Auth\SignIn\FailedToSignIn: Sign in failed: cURL error
60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
(see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in
Kreait\Firebase\Auth\SignIn\FailedToSignIn::fromPrevious() (line 39 of
C:\xampp\htdocs\dialog-lk-drupal\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Auth\SignIn\FailedToSignIn.php).


Please review [ask] and try again with your post. What have you researched in relation to this (common) error so far, what have you tried, where are you stuck, what do you need from the community which isn't already extensively documented online?

P.S. You are running an old, unsupported version of PHP. You should upgrade your PHP version urgently to continue to receive security updates. https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php . PHP (7.4) to went out of support 2 years ago (see https://www.php.net/eol.php). Running on current versions will increase security and reduce any issues with obsolete components or unsupported functionality.
